# @angular-redux/form:'formDirective' is defined as an accessor in class 'ControlContainer', overridden here in 'ConnectArray'

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, angular10, angular-redux

Updated my project from ***Angular 8 to Angular 10.***

**package.json** contains :

```
"@angular-redux/form": "6.7.0", 
"@angular-redux/store": "7.1.1", 
"@angular/cdk": "10.2.5",
"@angular/common": "10.1.6",
"@angular/core": "10.1.6",
"@angular/flex-layout": "10.0.0-beta.32",
"@angular/forms": "10.1.6",
"redux": "3.7.2",
"redux-logger": "3.0.6",
"redux-observable": "0.17.0",
"redux-observable-es6-compat": "1.2.1",
"rxjs": "6.6.3",
"rxjs-compat": "6.5.3"
```

After migrating to Angular 10 , i am getting below error,

**Error**

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular-redux/form/dist/source/connect-array/connect-array.d.ts:29:14 - error TS2610: 'formDirective' is defined as an accessor in class 'ControlContainer', but is overridden here in 'ConnectArray' as an instance property.

29     readonly formDirective: FormGroupDirective;
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular-redux/form/dist/source/connect-array/connect-array.d.ts:30:14 - error TS2610: 'path' is defined as an accessor in class 'ControlContainer', but is overridden here in 'ConnectArray' as an instance property.

30     readonly path: Array<string>;
```

Tried to update @angular-redux/form and @angular-redux/store to latest version, still getting the same error.